# How to add an application to drop-down menu under "open with another application" on RHEL 7

Tags: rhel, gui, application

I have a .py script that I want to have the option to open with Spyder when I right-click on the file icon. If I right click on the script and select the "open with another application" command I get a list of programs installed on my computer that I can use to open the file with, however, Spyder is not one of the selected lists.

[image]

Spyder appears under my Applications>engineerng tab from the main drop-down menu.  in my `/usr/share/applications` folder, I have the following Spyder.desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=spyder
Name=spyder
GenericName=Scientific Python Development Environment
Comment=A simple and lightweighted python IDE with MATLAB-like features
Icon=/home/adowney2/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/static/images/spyder-icon-1024x1024.png
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Engineering;Mathematics;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default file associations are stored in `/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list`. User customizations can be added to `~/.config/mimeapps.list`. Note that per-user settings (in `~/.config/mimeapps.list`) trump system-wide settings. In this case, you would add a line like this:

```
text/x-python=spyder.desktop
```

This makes *Spyder* the default application for opening Python files. You can also add other apps to make them available through the **Open With Other Application** menu item, such as:

```
text/x-python=spyder.desktop;org.gnome.gedit.desktop;
```

[image: RHEL7 GNOME Context Menu with Python]

The above assumes that the `spyder.desktop` file was added to your system when you installed *Spyder*. I installed from the EPEL repository, which supplies this file in `/usr/share/applications/spyder.desktop`. If you installed from a different source that doesn't provide the file, add it as `~/.local/share/applications/spyder.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=spyder
Name=Spyder
GenericName=Scientific Python Development Environment
Comment=A simple and lightweighted python IDE with MATLAB-like features
Icon=spyder
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
```

See the documentation for [Overriding the Default Registered Application for Individual Users](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/desktop_migration_and_administration_guide/file_formats#registered-application-override-user) in the *RHEL Desktop Migration and Administration Guide*.

Comment: Thanks, however, I am still not able to get this to work. I added the line `text/x-python=spyder.desktop;org.gnome.gedit.desktop;` to my '/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list' file. I have the spyder.desktop file that I added to the question description. I looked at the link you provided but it seems that I have to add a .xml file to `/usr/share/mime/packages/application-x-newtype.xml' for the .py file extensions. This seems more complicated than it should be.

Comment: @Austin, you shouldn't need to add the MIME definition (the XML) file because it already exists in the default installation (`/usr/share/mime/text/x-python.xml`, which is installed by the *shared-mime-info* package). Check if this file exists. If it does, check the `spyder.desktop` file for correctness. I just tried the described steps, and it worked as expected.

Comment: Sorry, still not working. I did check and I do have the file `usr/share/mime/text/x-python.xml`, and my file names are correct. From the terminal, if I use `ls` to list the files in `/usr/share/applications/` I see `spyder.desktop`. I updated my file to match yours, see the updated question and I have restarted my computer a few times.  I am working completely out of the `/usr/share/applications/` locations, I am not sure what the `config/mimeapps.list` is referring to. Should I be updating this?

Comment: Ok, I now see that `.config/mimeapps.list' is under `home/usr`. If I open this file I have a only one line under default applications that reads `text/x-python=org.gnome.gedit.desktop;`, I changed this to `[Default Applications]
text/x-python=spyder.desktop;org.gnome.gedit.desktop;` and everything works fine. If you could point this out in your answer that would be amazing!  The main issue is that there are many `mimeapps.list` in the system and I just needed to update the correct one.

Comment: OK, I added a note saying the per-user settings take preference over system-wide settings. Glad you were able to get it working.